# Difficulty with filtering nearest neighbor for an SKSpriteNode and the size of said node(swift, spritekit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a node named "user" and it runs an animation through user.atlas constantly. It is also pixel art (18x50) and I need it to stay looking sharp and how I designed it. If I remove the action and add

```
user.texture?.filteringMode = .Nearest
```

it looks sharp and clear and perfect - but as soon as I add the action, the texture don't seem to want to follow that rule.

Also!

The image is stretched, even if I set the size to (18 , 50) it still is stretched vertically and the pixels are longer than they are wide. This problem persists no matter the animation.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: because you need to make sure all the textures in the animation follow the rule as well

Comment: @Knight0fDragon can you elaborate? i know that's why but I'm not sure how to apply it to the whole atlas.

Comment: You dont apply it to the atlas, you apply it to each texture before you add it to the array

Comment: This looks old. I guess not many people use spritekit for their projects or they do not like pixelart :)

Answer (score 0):

You should set filtering mode of the textures before you add to the sprite.

Here is an example:

```
// this creates a walking character with endless loop

// create textures of the sprite
let frame1 : SKTexture = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "walk-left-1")
let frame2 : SKTexture = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "walk-left-2")
let frame3 : SKTexture = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "walk-left-3")
let frame4 : SKTexture = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "walk-left-4")

// set filter for pixelart
frame1.filteringMode = .nearest
frame2.filteringMode = .nearest
frame3.filteringMode = .nearest
frame4.filteringMode = .nearest

// create the textures array
let walkFrames = [frame1, frame2, frame3, frame4]

// create sprite and add to the scene
let sprite = SKSpriteNode.init(texture: walkFrames[0])
sprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
self.addChild(sprite)

// create the walking animation  
let animate = SKAction.animate(with: walkFrames, timePerFrame: 0.2) 

//OPTIONAL: make sprite bigger if you need
sprite.setScale(4)

// start walking
sprite.run(SKAction.repeatForever(animate))
```